# How to generate random numbers in sql?

Tags: sql-server, command

How to generate unique and random numbers (5 characters) in sql command?

Sample data:

```
Column K_ID and many row 
ID1:63487 
ID2:21583
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `NEWID()`

```
select  10000 + abs(convert(bigint, convert(varbinary(20), newid()))) % 90000
```

Comment: OP - This is an excellent way to generate a number with a length of 5 but you still have to check and call this again (and again, and again) if it returns a value you already have. And with a length of 5 numbers you are going to run out pretty quickly.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT RIGHT('0000' + CAST(CAST(FLOOR(RAND() * 10000) as int) as varchar(5)), 5)
```

Comment: Just a minor detail: should be * 100000. At the moment it results in 01441 for example.

Comment: If you try to do this in a query the Rand() function will calculate a value once, then re-use that same value on every line in the return.